# Set background color accordion heading

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to change the color of an accordion depending on status on the current item in the list.

I want to use something like `ng-class="{status: item.status}"` (where I have `testClass: true`)

The problem now is that I can't set the color of the whole accordion heading.

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="item in items" class="animate-repeat" is-open="status.open">
        <accordion-heading>
            <div ng-class="{testClass: true}">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </accordion-heading>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="text-content font-size-14">{{item.text}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

CSS

```
.testClass {
background-color: burlywood;
}
```

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

I found similar problem here, but the solution didn't work for me
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3038

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/f8ce1b0w/2/

Comment: did you try setting  ng-class="{testClass: true}" at the accordion header level

Comment: @Mudassar Yes, i tried to set it on accordion-group but that didn't work. And I can't add it above that since the iteration is in accordion-group

Comment: I was referring to <accordion-heading>

Comment: @Mudassar My misstake. But that won't work either.

Comment: How do I get the size of the parent? That's really the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the class to the 'accordion-group' and then style with css.

HTML

```
<accordion-group ng-controller='MyAccordionGroupController' class="test" is-open="isopen">
```

CSS

```
.panel {
  &.test {
    & > .panel-heading {
      background-color: red;
    }
  } 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BramG/f8ce1b0w/8/

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to your problem

```
.test{
  background-color: red;
}

 .test-parent.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    background-color:red;
}

<accordion-group ng-controller='MyAccordionGroupController' is-open="isopen" class="test-parent">
        <accordion-heading>
         <div class="test">
          I can have markup, too!
          </div>
        </accordion-heading>
        This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
      </accordion-group>
```

Comment: Yes, that changes the color. But how do I use that with ng-class to set different colors due to the status?

Comment: made the change accordingly and you need to repeat the accordion rather than the accordion group

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to move the applied class higher in the hierarchy:

http://jsfiddle.net/f8ce1b0w/7/

Then your css will look like :

```
.panel-warning .panel-heading {
  //customize your css here
}
```

The problem is you are placing the test-item inside an item with padding.  Instead, place the test-item-class higher up, and then use css to target the items.

If your states will match to Bootstrap states, then you may want the validation class names from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#panels
(panel-success, panel-info, panel-warning, panel-danger)

These class names are already in your Bootstrap css.